# Donut Tutorial ep.10-Icing disappears from viewport but still in outliner

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

My icing shows in outliner but not in viewport or renders. I think the error happened after I cut and deleted “icing” object node in geo node editor and attached the sprinkles collection.. I’ve checked visibility settings and it nothing seems to be hidden.. please point me in right direction.. my biggest issue learning blender is making changes or mis-clicking but not knowing exactly what I changed and how to recover.

[image]

Comment: Hello please show a screenshot of your interface (and of your GeoNode window)

Comment: Added above to original post..

Comment: So what does it give if you plug your Group Input into the Join Geometry? https://zupimages.net/up/23/09/q1d4.jpg

Comment: Fixed!!! Thank you so much! I am guessing I probably cut the Group Input connection when I added sprinkles node.

Comment: @independentGeorge Well, you already wrote it in your question: _"I think the error happened after I cut and deleted “icing” object node in geo node editor"_, I mean the sprinkles are the only thing plugged in the _Join Geometry_ node - pretty useless joining something if it is the only geometry you plugged in there. When you suspected cutting and deleting the icing object was the cause, why didn't you reconnect it for the sake of testing this theory?

Answer (score 0):

Plug your *Group Input* into the *Join Geometry*, otherwise your object won't be visible:

[image]